# \limits for \oiint with mathdesign

Tags: math-mode, mathdesign

[image]

I'd like limits for `\oiint` shown the same way as for `\iint`. How can I do?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\iint_{M\in\mathcal{S}}   \oiint_{M\in\mathcal{S}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :-):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\[
\iint_{M\in\mathcal{S}}  \quad   \oiint\nolimits_{M\in\mathcal{S}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Don't know why it is not the default.

Comment: @cjorssen, me either. Probably the `oiint` is composed sign and in this is default position below (quit common practice at curve integrals).

Comment: @cjorssen: here's a guess as to why it's default: most of the time in math, if you're integrating from *a* to *b*, one uses the `\nolimits` notation, so `\int` defaults to `\nolimits`. However, if you integrate over a set *A*, it's more common to see `\int\limits_A`. Since `\oiint` doesn't really make sense "from *a* to *b*," I assume it would default to the more common notation for sets.

Comment: @cjorssen I guess that the standard practice for integrals over multidimensional domains is to use `\limits`; you can get `\nolimits` by default with `\let\oiintop\oiint\renewcommand{\oiint}{\oiintop\nolimits}` (in the preamble after having loaded `mathdesign`).